# plot tree in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tree

I wonder if it is possible to plot tree by ggplot?
let's say:

```
library(rpart
library(rpart.plot)

data(iris)
mod <- rpart(Species~., data=iris)
prp(mod)
```

[image]

Can I plot similar graph in ggplot?

Comment: Maybe the add-on package `ggdendro` is interesting for you. To my knowledge `ggplot2` has no built-in function to plot trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `autoplot.rpart()` function in the `survMisc` package could get you part of the way there. But you'd likely need to clean up the presentation of the the plot, potentially layering in symbols, etc. It seems to be just a starting point:

```
library(rpart)
library(survMisc)

data(iris)
mod <- rpart(Species~., data=iris)

autoplot(mod, branch=0)
```

[image: ggplot2 rpart fit]

Comment: `autoplot.rpart` is no longer part of the `survMisc` package.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *rattle*, which produces nice rpart plots

```
library(rattle)

fancyRpartPlot(rpart(Species~., data=iris),yesno=2,split.col="black",nn.col="black", 
               caption="",palette="Set2",branch.col="black")
```

[image: Link to my plots]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't realize rattle had this feature!