# Summary table visualized as a tree chart with R

Tags: r, charts, tree, visualization, summary

I'm trying to visualize a summary table as a tree in R.

Actually I saw there are some plots related to decision tree algorithms, but I don't need a machine learning model.

Is it possible to have a "flowchart/tree" without using a ML package?

Here is a summary table example:

| First step | Second step | Third step | Numeric |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B1 | C1 | 3 |
| A | B1 | C2 | 4 |
| A | B1 | C3 | 7 |
| A | B2 | C2 | 3 |
| A | B2 | C4 | 8 |

And this is the result I need as output:

[image: output example]

(Please note that I need to preserve the order of the steps.)

Thank you

Comment: Althought you are leaving the impression, SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried so far to achieve your goal?

Comment: Take a look at the vignettes for the [data.tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/) package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plot tree in ggplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087087/plot-tree-in-ggplot-in-r)